# How to get the count of values in a primitive array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, size

How to find the count of values in a primitive array in Java (not the length)?

```java
int[] array = new int[26];

array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    if (array[i] % 2 != 0)
        return false;
```

I want the count of the values (3), not the array length (26).

Is there any built-in function available to get this in Java?

Comment: why do you think that size is 3 for that array? just because other numbers are 0, what about `1 0 2` - what is the size of such array?

Comment: When you initialize an array like this, the array is filled with 0 values, so the size is 26. If you want to get the count of non-zero values in the array, you could do `Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i != 0).count()`.

Comment: I was using sizeof() function in c language it's print 1 2 3 . but java will print 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 . but I want array elements only .

Comment: Instead of using array you can used `List`

Comment: Initialise your array as `int[] array = {1,2,3};`, which is presumably exactly what you were doing in C.

Comment: And read an array tutorial, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score -4):

```
    int[] array = new int[26];

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < array[i]; i++)
            System.out.println(i);
```

remove length, if you add length() in the loop it will return the whole size of an array, instead, count the index of the element which will give the current size of an array.

Comment: This doesn't give any count, it just prints the values in the array.

Comment: How does this help OP? Have you read the question? What if the array was `[15, 2848, 329, 0, 0, 0, 0....]` instead?